# Change the icon tint of a MaterialButton icon programmatically [Kotlin]

Tags: android, kotlin, android-vectordrawable

I need to change the icon tint of my MaterialButton, the icon is a an xml vector asset and I can change the tint easily in the xml layout, but I need to change the color programmatically in a click, I can't be able to find something related of this issue, This is my button:

````
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/btnShowDepartmentList"
                style="@style/com.madison.Button.IconButton"
                app:iconSize="32dp"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_list_thumbnails"
                android:layout_width="42dp"
                android:layout_height="42dp"
                app:iconTint="@color/orangeLighter"
                tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"/> ```
````

Answer (score 12):

You will want to use the `setIconTint(ColorStateList)` or `setIconTintResource(Int)` methods of MaterialButton. For example:

```
val button = findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.btnShowDepartmentList)
button.setOnClickListener {
    button.setIconTintResource(R.color.orangeLighter)
}
```

Comment: you can't set a colour directly in setIconTint, it requires a colorStateList. instead, use setIconTintResource

Comment: Thanks @sudesh! I don't know if there was an older version of the library with that method or if I just got it wrong from the start, but I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to pass the ColorStateList to the iconTint programmatically.

```
btnShowDepartmentList.iconTint = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(activity, R.color.orangeLighter)
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
btnShowDepartmentThumbnails.setOnClickListener {
        btnShowDepartmentThumbnails.setIconTintResource(R.color.orangeLighter)            
    }
```

My error was tried to set icon tint, with this way:

```
 btnShowDepartmentThumbnails.setOnClickListener {
            it.setIconTintResource(R.color.orangeLighter)            
        }
```

Comment: The reason that doesn't work is that the type of `it` in the lambda is `View!` (remember that the `onClick()` method of the interface is passed an argument `View v`), and the method you're trying to call is a method of `MaterialButton`. You could perform casting if you wanted to use `it`: `(it as MaterialButton).foo()`